# default Users and failed jobs table not showing up when first run the artisan migration command in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, database-migration

just a question, which looks weird to me
After successfully creating a database and my first table in my Postgres, unfortunately, when I run migration command the default migration-like users, failed jobs table not showing up but these 2 PHP files were shown under my migration folder and in public folder in my db

[image]

Did I miss any steps?..will it affected my newly created laravel project?

Answer (score 1):

If your failed_jobs table is missing then you should run below two commands for generating .

```
php artisan queue:failed-table
php artisan migrate
```